# Include optional psuedo classes in SCSS selector.

Tags: css, sass

If if have something like:

```
input, select {
  &:focus {
    border: solid 1px blue;
  }
}

.has-error {
  input, select {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
}
```

Then an input within a `.has-error` will still be styled blue, because the `input:focus` is more specific.

Is there an elegant way to override this? 
The best I've got is:

```
input, select {
  &:focus {
    border: solid 1px blue;
  }
}

.has-error {
  input, select, input:focus, select:focus {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more nesting:

```
.has-error {
  input, select {
    &, &:focus {
      border: solid 1px red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post this myself now! :)